# Using the Residue Theorem for Complex Integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

I want to calculate the following integral:
$\int_{|z-i| = 10} \left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^4$. I have been told to use the Residue Theorem, but I couldn't accomplish a correct calculation. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\left(z+\frac1z\right)^4$ is an even function, if you expand that expression, then the coefficient of $\frac1z$ will be $0$. Therefore, by the residue theorem, your integral is equal to $2\pi i\times0=0$.

Comment: Ah that was quick. Thank you!